# Is there a way to do this without nested using nested promise?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-functions

In the below cloud function, I am populating a collection-1 with an autogenerated ID and 5 field values. While adding each document, I am populating another collection with the document name as one of the properties containing the earlier auto-generated document name as the field,

```
Collection-1
    -auto-id
          -property1
          -property2
          -property3
Collection-2
    property2
          -auto-id from collection-1
```

Collection-2 is maintained for faster lookup of the data.

```
exports.addSafe = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // The HTTP endpoint is going to receive an object with an attribute "data", which is going to contain an array of objects with every single safe data point to add

        for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                db.collection('Safes').add(data[i])
                .then((docRef) => {

                    db.collection('Safes-Hardware').doc(data[i]['Mac address Check']).set({
                        "ID" : docRef.id
                    })
                    .then((value) =>{
                        console.log("Reference added with ID: ", value.id);
                        return { message: "Successful" }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('Oops!, error while adding lookup details',err);
                        return { message: "Error while adding lookup details",err }
                    })
                    console.log('Mac written with ID: ', docRef.id); 
                    return { message: "Success is within the palm of our hands." }
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log('Error logged', err);
                })

        }
    }
})
```

Updated Code - Using nested async-await

```
exports.addSafe = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    // The HTTP endpoint is going to receive an object with an attribute "data", which is going to contain an array of objects with every single safe data point to add

    const attributesToDelete = ["CARTON#", "NO#"] // This first function call is implemented initially because of the first CSV file that I was given, which includes unnecessary columns, like "Carton" or "No". The factory producing the safes should send a CSV file with no unecessary extra data. If they do, this function should theoretically take care of removing those data points, to ensure that the database only holds the necessary data points ;)
    deleteAttributes(data, attributesToDelete);
    let validated = true;

    //validateForm(data);

    if (validated === false) {
        console.log('Data cannot be validated. Misses the correct attributes')
    } else {

        for (let i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
                try
                {

                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
                    var ifPresent = db.collection("Safes-Hardware").doc(data[i]['Mac address Check']);
                    ifPresent.get()
                    .then(async (doc)=>{
                        if (!doc.exists) 
                        {
                            console.log("Document does not exit. Proceeding to add");
                            try{
                                // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
                                const docRef = await db.collection('Safes').add(data[i])
                                console.log('Mac written with ID: ', docRef.id); 
                                try{
                                    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
                                    await db.collection('Safes-Hardware').doc(data[i]['Mac address Check'])
                                    .set({
                                            "ID" : docRef.id
                                        })
                                    console.log("Reference added");
                                }
                                catch(err){
                                    console.log("Error while adding reference",err)
                                } 
                            }
                            catch(err){
                                console.log("Error while adding data to 'Safe' collection")
                            }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            console.log("Document exists in database. Skipping safe with MAC Address: ",data[i]['Mac address Check']);
                        }
                        return { message: "Success is within the palm of our hands." } 
                    })
                    .catch((error)=>{
                        console.log("Error while checking for duplicates", error);

                    });

                }
                catch(error){
                    console.log("Error logged",error)
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

What would be a better way to do this instead of using nested promises?
When I am not populating the second collection- the code works flawlessly. But when the second collection is also being populated - I get the following error once in a while (3/10 times)

Error:

```
 Error logged { Error: The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid.
    at Http2CallStream.call.on (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/client.js:96:45)
    at emitOne (events.js:121:20)
    at Http2CallStream.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at process.nextTick (/srv/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/build/src/call-stream.js:71:22)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
  code: 3,
  details: 'The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid.',
  metadata: Metadata { options: undefined, internalRepr: Map {} } }
```

[Collections - Safe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxk4M.png)

[Safes-Hardware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5HJh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to just first create a collection with the [Custom Document Name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) and then set the data into the document as following:

```
 const doc = db.collection('Safes').doc(data[i]['Mac address Check'])
 doc.set({"ID" : docRef.id })
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215871/discussion-on-answer-by-nibrass-h-is-there-a-way-to-do-this-without-nested-using).